# android layout - top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Using either relative or linear layouts, how can I have a text field at the top of layout centered horizontally and at the bottom have 4 buttons all displayed on the same line with equal space between them?

Comment: Your question sounds like someone gave you it as homework, you should attempt this yourself and then if you still encounter difficulty ask a question with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="btn 1 " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
            android:text="btn 2 " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2"
            android:text="btn 3 " />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3"
            android:text="btn 4 " />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: good answer, does exactly what i asked. how could i center horizontally those buttons at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

For the top button, you can do that using the Graphical Layout interface. Just add your textfield, and set it the following properties :

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

For the bottom buttons you should add a LinearLayout with the following properties :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

and put your 4 buttons with `android:layout_weight="1"` inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Android!"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```